# MySQL update table from another table values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as `finance_mpc_budget` and `finance_mpc_issues`. They are **joined** with following condition-

```
finance_mpc_budget.mpc_budget_id = finance_mpc_issues.ref_no
```

So, I need to update `finance_mpc_issues.ref_no` using

```
finance_mpc_budget.mpc_budget_id where finance_mpc_budget.mpc_budget_id > 55
```

To do this I used the following query

```
UPDATE finance_mpc_issues 
JOIN (
      SELECT mpc_budget_id FROM finance_mpc_budget
      WHERE finance_mpc_budget.mpc_budget_id > 55 
      ORDER BY mpc_budget_id) a 
ON a.mpc_budget_id = finance_mpc_issues.ref_no 
SET finance_mpc_issues.ref_no = a.mpc_budget_id
```

But it generated the empty result set. What may be the wrong. Can anyone help me?

## finance_mpc_budget table

```
+---------------+----------+--------+
| mpc_budget_id | category | amount |
+---------------+----------+--------+
|             56| A        |  22000 |
|             57| B        |  25000 |
|             58| C        |  45000 |
|             59| D        |  16000 |
+---------------+----------+--------+
```

## finance_mpc_issues table

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| issues_id | ref_no | amount |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|        10 |        |  22000 |
|        11 |        |  25000 |
|        12 |        |  45000 |
|        13 |        |  16000 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

## Desired output

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| issues_id | ref_no | amount |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|        10 |      56|  22000 |
|        11 |      57|  25000 |
|        12 |      58|  45000 |
|        13 |      59|  16000 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: What's the point of updating `finance_mpc_issues.ref_no` by `finance_mpc_budget.mpc_budget_id` if you are joining this 2 tables by this fields, which means the are already the same (otherwise you wouldn't be able to join them)?

Comment: As per the updated question: there is no way to join this 2 tables (there is no reliable join key is defined on both tables). You could possibly join my amount (ugghhhh), but that's not reliable enough. So the simple answer is to reach desired outcome, you had to design your tables schema along with relations more thoughtfully in the first place. What you are trying to do is retrofitting join key into `finance_mpc_issues` table. This is not how it works.

Comment: you can't join using `ref_no` since it is null. the `amount` column seems  to hold identical value. you can join using `amount` to have desired output. Does actually `amount` of two tables are same for each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
update finance_mpc_issues 
join finance_mpc_budget a on a.mpc_budget_id = finance_mpc_issues.ref_no
set  finance_mpc_issues.ref_no=a.mpc_budget_id
where a.mpc_budget_id >55
```

Comment: But also got the empty result set

Comment: @MCITTrends why do you expect a result set for an `update` operation?

Comment: @Erfan. the ref_no of finance_mpc_issues table is still empty. To join these tables it must be insert mpc_budget_id of finance_mpc_budget table to ref_no of finance_mpc_issues table

Answer (score -1):

You can not `join` using `ref_no` since it is null. Therefore your `finance_mpc_issues` table is not updated.

*Based on your table and data*, I **assume** `amount` column holds identical value. Therefore using `amount` column you can have your desired output.

```
Update finance_mpc_issues fi
set fi.ref_no = 
  (select fb.mpc_budget_id 
     from finance_mpc_budget fb 
     WHERE fb.amount = fi.amount
  );
```

[fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pioRAQUx2AMmqse9g35hq7/1)